# SQL or PIG script to restructure a table to reflect Columns in repeating rows

Tags: sql, apache-pig

So I have a table

```
ID Tag1 Tag2 Tag3
1   a    b
2   a    b    c
3   a
```

I would like to transform this table to

```
ID Tag
1   a
1   b
2   a
2   b
2   c
3   a
```

using PIG latin or SQL?

Comment: it would be easier in sql using `union`.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server you can do it with the PIVOT command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SQL` you can do this by using `UNION ALL`

```
select Id, Tag1 From yourtable Where Tag1 <> ''
Union All
select Id, Tag2 From yourtable Where Tag2 <> ''
Union All
select Id, Tag3 From yourtable Where Tag3 <> ''
```

If you don't want duplicates then change `UNION ALL` to `UNION`. This can done efficiently if your database engine supports `unpivot` operator

Comment: Thank you both the union and the unpivot are exactly what I was looking for. appreciate your help